# Quick one: clarity or short code?

Tags: java, list, collections

Ok, as I promised quick one so here we go:

I got fragment of code that just tokenizes string `in` by `in.split("");`, so I get all characters separately and then I remove those that I don't want, and currently it looks like this:

```
List<String> op=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(in.split("")));
op.removeAll(removable);
operators=op.toArray(new String[op.size()]);
```

where `op` is my temporary variable to handle the removal. Is there any way to put it in one line? And if there is(pls tell me how, I was wondering for some time and I figured there isn't because `removeAll()` returns boolean) - should it be done or should I stay this way to make it easier to read?

Comment: What is the type of `removable`?

Comment: What about changing that into: `String result = in.replaceAll(removable, "");`, assuming `removable` is a String?

Comment: @11684 `List.removeAll(Collection)` takes a Collection.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I was referring to `String#replaceAll`. Note that `in` is a string, per the OP. "...that tokenizes string `in`..."

Comment: `removable` is also a `List<String>`, `replaceAll` is useful too, maybe I'll find use for this solution

Comment: @PeterLawrey Now I get it, you were referring to `removable`, not in. Stupidstupidstupidstupid. I'll see if I can save my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove letters, regex would be a better choice.  A String is an array of characters, and you don't need to use a List to process it.

```
String removable = "[a-zA-Z0-9]";
String operators = in.replaceAll(removable, "");
```

This gives you a String of the non-removable characters.

if removable is a collection you can turn it back into a String with.

```
String regex = "["+(removable.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()))+"]";
String operators = in.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

You can inline the `regex` to make it a one liner.

---

If you want to remove words, you need Java 8 streams to turn this into a one liner (Unless you write a method to do this which you can call in one line)

```
List<String> operators = Stream.of(in.split(" "))
                               .filter(s -> !removable.contains(s))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, to make it readable, you still end up using three newlines. ;)

Comment: I think you misread the question; the OP uses `.split("")` to get a list of all the characters, which is quite different from splitting on all spaces, as you seem to do in your snippet.

Comment: Where does that regex come from? The contents of `removable` aren't given in the question.

Comment: well, that's basically what I was looking for and google did not bless me with similar answer. I want operators to stay as `List<String>` and now I got the idea how to make it nice and easy.

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* need Java 8 for this:

```
String result = in.replaceAll(removable, "");
```

(I assumed `removable` is a String.)

This works by replacing every occurrence of the string `removable` by an empty string, essentially removing it.

**Note:**

If `removable` contains (a) metacharacter(s), you should prepend it with "\\". Peter Lawrey had the brilliant idea that doing this: `removable = "[" + removable + "]";` works as well for most metacharacters.

If you want the end result to be a `List<String>`, you can just add `.split("");` at the end:

List result = in.replaceAll(removable, "").split("");

**EDIT**

As Peter Lawrey pointed out quite early, `removable` is not a String. If you somehow cannot change `removable` to a String (which I think would be much easier), you could still convert it to a string using this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
for (String s : removable) {
  sb.append(s);
}
sb.append("]");
String removableString = sb.toString();
```

(The brackets ( [ ] ) are needed for the regex, they basically mean "match any char between us".)

You used `removable` to remove items from a list of single-char Strings, so I assumed that all items of `removable` are also single-char Strings. If that is not the case, so you change the line inside the for-loop to `sb.append("(").append(s).append(")");`.
And with the string, you can finally do:

```
in.removeAll(removable, "").split("");
```

Comment: `removeable` needs to be a regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, but passed as a String. AFAIK, a single character is a valid regex. @PeterLawrey

Comment: True, unless it is `.` or `+` or a symbol which has a special meaning to a regex. ;)

Comment: Nice catch. Let me add a note to my answer.

Comment: Adding `[` and `]` will fix it for most symbols.

Answer (score 0):

ok, as for readability it remains unclear and depends on personal feeling Peter Lawrey and 11684 answers let me find solution, which was right before my eyes. I was creating `removable` using `for` to add by ascii code all characters that I want to dispose, but as it was pointed out, small regex would be thousand times better. for start I only want to remove digits, but I'll move on later to sanitizing whole input if needed.

```
String[] operators=in.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").split("");
```

this way, because I needed it as String array, but of course it's can also go as `List' if I may want to(gonna try tomorrow):

```
List<String> op=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(in.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").split("")));
```

and it's one liner. but well, I think it's not easy to read for anyone but author.